# google is not defined google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, prototype

I'm trying to extend my prototype function from google.maps.Map object. But I'm getting the Cannot read property 'firstChild' of undefined.

Basically I just want to add a custom prototype object that is also an instance of google.maps.Map Below is my code

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing" async defer></script>

function Map(id, options) {
    this.id = id;
    this.latlng = options.center;
}

Map.prototype = new google.maps.Map;

function initMap()
{
    map = new Map('map', mapOptions);
}
```

and here's the error I'm getting[image]

So what I like is when I run 'new Map('map', mapOptions)' this will create a new google.maps.Map(); instance and this will render a map. But I'm not sure what I'm missing here as I'm fairly new to using prototype in javascript. Hope you can help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error you are having right now is because of the async and defer attribute on the script tag, take a look here http://peter.sh/experiments/asynchronous-and-deferred-javascript-execution-explained/

**Update after comment "I tried removing the async and defer but a new error of cannot find 'firstchild'"**

The following snippet will only work from w3schools try it editor because of the google maps API key.

**Update to use inheritance**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>

    <h1>My First Google Map</h1>

    <div id="googleMap" style="width:100%;height:400px;"></div>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBu-916DdpKAjTmJNIgngS6HL_kDIKU0aU"></script>
    <script>
      function Map(id, options) {
       var element = document.getElementById(id);
        // Call constructor of superclass to initialize superclass-derived members.
        google.maps.Map.call(this, element, options);
        
        this.id = id;
        this.latlng = options.center;

        this.customAddMarkerAtCenter = function(){
          return new google.maps.Marker({
            position: this.latlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Hello World!'
          });
        }
      }

      Map.prototype = Object.create(google.maps.Map.prototype);
      Map.prototype.constructor = Map;


      function initMap()
      {
        map = new Map( "googleMap" , {
          center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),
          zoom:5
        }, "mapId");
       
      map.customAddMarkerAtCenter();
    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(50.508742,-0.120850),
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
        });
        
        alert(map.id )
        alert(map.latlng )
      }
     
      
      
      initMap();
    </script>


    <!--
To use this code on your website, get a free API key from Google.
Read more at: https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_basic.asp
-->

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried removing the async and defer but a new error of cannot find 'firstchild'

Comment: Yes, but this is another error, i have solved what you asked for, i will update my answer with a working demo

Comment: Tried your approach but still the same. Also I would like to make the new Map prototype to behave just like google.maps.Map object. In short I want it to inherit everything google.maps.Map object has

Comment: No luck still the same

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: I'm using chrome and I'm still getting the same error. Tried running the same script.

Comment: Can you post the code you are running and the error message. With environment are you using?

Comment: I found a work around. I just added a new function and then if I want to reference the instance of google.map I just do map.instance. Anyways thanks for the help